# property $\omega$-limit set

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]
[image]

I’m guessing that by $y^j$ they mean a sequence in $\omega(x_0)$. But I don’t understand what they mean by “limits of points converging to $y^j$”. Shouldn’t the limit of those points be exactly $y^j$?

In any case, I’m kind of confused how this shows that each limit sequence lies in $\omega(x_0)$. Like what happens when we combine those points? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What book is it? There might be some context elsewhere in the chapter.

Answer (score 1):

I guess they mean the following: let $\{ y^j : j \in \mathbb{N} \} \subseteq \omega(x_0)$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{j \to \infty} y^j = y^{\infty}$. For each $n \geqslant 1$ pick $y^j$ such that $|y^j - y^{\infty}| \leqslant \frac{1}{n}$ and then pick $t_n \geqslant n$ such that $|\phi(t_n; x_0) - y^j| \leqslant \frac{1}{n}$. Then

$$|\phi(t_n; x_0) - y^{\infty}| \leqslant |\phi(t_n; x_0) - y^j| + |y^j - y^{\infty}| \leqslant \frac{2}{n},$$

hence $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \phi(t_n; x_0) = y^{\infty}$ and $t_n \to \infty$, therefore $y^{\infty} \in \omega(x_0)$.

As to the wording, if we pick $\{ t_i^j \}$ so that for each $j \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $t_i^j \to \infty$ and $\phi(t_i^j; x_0) \to y^j$ as $i \to \infty$, then the sequence $t_n$ as above can be constructed by combining some terms of those $t_i^j$'s. There isn't much precision in the description from the book, but I think that's what was meant.